# Problem using computed property with Typescript to sort array

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to use Vue in a typescript single page application, where a series of arrays need shown in lists on screen but need to be shown sorted. Seems like a simple and straightforward problem, but none of the examples I have seem to work in Typescript. Can someone give me a working example on how you can get typescript to accept a Vue computed function from an array in the Vue data?

I have made an orderedRegions computed function in the Vue config.  This is supposed to return a sorted version of the Vue data object called "Regions".  The intended result is that ordredRegions will return the same list sorted alphabetically.

```
    computed: {
      orderedRegions: function () : Region[] {
        function compare(x : Region, y: Region) {
          if (x.name < y.name) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (x.name > y.name) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        }
        return this.Regions.sort(compare);
      }
    }
```

I have determined that if I strip out the typescript parts, and insert this into my compiled javascript file it does indeed work, but the typescript will not compile because the "this.Regions" object is shown as an error as not existing.  It appears Typescript in Visual Studio Code is expecting "this" to refer to the function scope, not the Vue scope.

Any thoughts on how I make Typescript happy with this?

..additional attempts based on feedback:
1) I tried using "shorthand" as per below, but appears to have same results. "this" is referring to the function, not Vue, and Typescript gives the error : "Property 'Regions' does not exist on type '{ sortedRegions: () => any; orderedRegions(): Region[]; }"

```
orderedRegions() : Region[] {
    function compare(x : Region, y: Region) {
        if (x.name < y.name) {
            return -1;
        }
            if (x.name > y.name) {
            return 1;
        }
            return 0;
        }
        return this.Regions.sort(compare);
    }
```

2) I have also tried the arrow function, and again the same error from Typescript:

```
orderedRegions: () => {
    function compare(x : Region, y: Region) {
        if (x.name < y.name) {
            return -1;
        }
            if (x.name > y.name) {
            return 1;
        }
            return 0;
    }
    return this.Regions.sort(compare);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing `orderedRegions` as an arrow function?

Comment: Yes either use arrow functions or shorthand function definitions in your `computed`-object

Comment: I think I have tried both the arrow functions and the shorthand function, as per the edited above, but I still get the same problems.  Typescript seems to think my scope is the function, not the Vue object.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well for my typescript project I use class based api. If you use class based api, you can just have a `get function` which order the list. The getter get identified as computed function.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item of orderedList" :key="item" xs3>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
/** TODO: This component is very similar than the all orders component
 * We can really merge these 2 components some time in the future
 */
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class List extends Vue {
    private unorderedList = ["zTest", "fTest", "aTest", "gTest"];

    get orderedList() {
        return this.unorderedList.sort();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the regions to the `orderedRegions` function, then you don't have the `this` problem when in the function itself.

```
orderedRegions(myRegions: Region[]) : Region[] {
    function compare(x : Region, y: Region) {
        if (x.name < y.name) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (x.name > y.name) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return myRegions.sort(compare);
}
```

I have tested this and it works. In fact I have used your sorting function.

It's also better for testing since you don't have to worry about the `this` context.